# Interaction between base::max() and dplyr::case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

### Problem

I'm trying to write a `dplyr::case_when` statement that uses `max` to work out a Government benefit payable at various levels of income. The amount payable to recipients is reduced by a fixed amount once they pass a certain income level. They cannot receive less than $0 (they can't become net payers). *So a floor is needed in the calculation*.

When using the `max` function, the `benefit` variable (below) is held constant at $237 when `income` is between $53,728 and $94,316. I don't understand why this is happening.

If the `max` function is removed I get the right answer, but only for part of the range. I still need a way to introduce a floor of $0 to the `benefit` variable in the `dplyr::case_when` statement.

### My attempt

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(
  income = 53728:100000,
  benefit = case_when(
    income <= 53728 ~ 237.89,
    between(income, 53728, 94316) ~ max(237.89 - ((income - 53725) * 0.20), 0),
    TRUE            ~ 0
  )
)


#Quick plot of the variables
ggplot(df, aes(x = income, benefit)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_light() + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `pmax` instead of `max.`

```
> tibble( income = 53728:100000,  benefit = case_when( income <= 53728 ~
> 237.89,  between(income, 53728, 94316) ~ pmax(237.89 - ((income - 53725) * 0.20), 0),  TRUE ~ 0 )
```

The p in `pmax` stands for parallel. While `max` only returns a single number `pmax` returns a vector.